# can we customize the height and width of the facebook invite friends javascript api?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am developing a mobile website and I have integrated the facebook invite friends api into it. But the invite friends window is not fitting my browser window. Is there a way to customize the height and width of this request dialog?

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no parameters you can use to resize the invite friends popup that facebook provides. The height / width is fixed to a specific dimension. You can try using jQuery to hack the width / height of the frame.